# Get Rid of Spaces between > and <

Tags: html, perl, compression

I use the following code:

```
    $page_entire_code =~ s/> +?</></g;
```

to remove spaces between `>` and `<` in my HTML web pages. However, I noticed that it messes up my web page's breadcrumbs. For example:

```
<div id="breadcrumb" itemprop="breadcrumb">
  <b>
    You are here: <a href="http://www.romancestuck.com/">RomanceStuck</a> > <a href="http://www.romancestuck.com/marriage/love-and-marriage.htm">Marriage</a> > 11 Tips for Improving a Strained Relationship
  </b>
</div>
```

gets compressed to:

```
<div id="breadcrumb" itemprop="breadcrumb"><b>You are here: <a href="http://www.romancestuck.com/">RomanceStuck</a> ><a href="http://www.romancestuck.com/marriage/love-and-marriage.htm">Marriage</a> > 11 Tips for Improving a Strained Relationship</b></div>
```

The `>` after the `RomanceStuck` link doesn't have a space after it like it should. How can I change my Perl substitution line so that it doesn't mess up my breadcrumbs? I was thinking maybe I could say replace `>` that come after any characters except a space.

Thanks!

Comment: Your breadcrumbs are wrong. You should use `&gt;`.

Comment: i think you may use &gt or &lt for greater than and less than symbols which would allow you spaces as you wish.

Comment: Information you have given is not sufficient to answer your question. You may get a suggestion if you tell us why you are slurping the HTML content in the variable and then trying to filter spaces from it. Where are you getting this HTML content from? Do you have control on it if we suggest some changes to that content?

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="breadcrumb" itemprop="breadcrumb">
  <b>
    You are here: <a href="http://www.romancestuck.com/">RomanceStuck</a> &gt; <a href="http://www.romancestuck.com/marriage/love-and-marriage.htm">Marriage</a> &gt; 11 Tips for Improving a Strained Relationship
  </b>
</div>
```

replaced `>` with `&gt;`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can replace `>` by `&gt;` in your html code

```
<div id="breadcrumb" itemprop="breadcrumb">
  <b>
    You are here: <a href="http://www.romancestuck.com/">RomanceStuck</a> &gt; <a href="http://www.romancestuck.com/marriage/love-and-marriage.htm">Marriage</a> &gt; 11 Tips for Improving a Strained Relationship
  </b>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex maybe: />(\s|\n)?(<|[a-Z])/
Replaced by empty character. It should remove whitespace or line return between closing tag and opening one or any text.

Answer (score 0):

To "replace > that come after any characters except a space" you would do:

```
$page_entire_code =~ s/([^ ]>) +?</$1</g;
```

or on more recent perls,

```
$page_entire_code =~ s/[^ ]>\K +?</</g;
```

(though the ? there is useless; you are matching all spaces up to a `<`; it doesn't make sense to say match fewer of them if possible.)

Comment: $page_entire_code =~ s/([^ ]>) +?</$1</g; works!

Thanks so much!